# What html elements can be floated around

Tags: html, css, browser, css-float

I tried have some pre formated user input placed in a `<pre>` tag to retain its formatting such as line breaks, white space ect. However I also needed this text to be flowing around a div...you know floating around it. However it seems only `<p>` elements adhere to this behaviour of flowing around while still being a block level element which is in itself important to the layout so that I can modify the margin-top, margin-bottom of the text.

So question is: How can I make block formatted elements float around a floated element?

Comment: I don't really know what you are asking, but block vs inline: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline also, you can set {display: block}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<pre>` element will flow around floated elements as in this example. It also accepts margin and padding. Padding is in this example.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

pre {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Floated</div> 
<pre>Nam fermentum vitae 
  purus eu vestibulum. 
  Curabitur vitae 
Nam fermentum vitae 
  purus eu vestibulum. 
  Curabitur vitae 
Nam fermentum vitae 
  purus eu vestibulum. 
  Curabitur vitae 
Nam fermentum vitae 
  purus eu vestibulum. 
  Curabitur vitae 
Nam fermentum vitae 
  purus eu vestibulum. 
  Curabitur vitae 
 </pre>
```

Comment: can you either push that text down a bit or add more words to the paragraph so that it literally flows around the floated element? I literally want it to FLOW AROUND the box Thanks for your help and sorry for my obscurity

Comment: Sure, the example is updated with more text. It seems to work unless there's some other detail you need.

Comment: This hasnt been happening for me at all. lolz Thanks you confirm this should be happening by default.

Comment: If your having the same trouble as me. The problem is the bootstrap css file. set overflow:inital and remove the padding and it will Flow around